# Fit buttons inside a flex container with wrap support

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have the following problem:

I have a *dynamic* slideshow, which contains pictures of different dimensions and the slide buttons, which are in a flex container (it's not a requirement! just my try) need to be positioned correctly inside.

By positioned correctly I mean the slider buttons are positioned on the left and right and be the correct size to not cover up too much of the picture.

What I've tried so far:

I've tried using Flexboxes, `flow-grow`, Flex Container, setting the position to relative or absolute, using `transform`, writing this function:

```
// this function scales the child in the parent container
function scale() {
  document.querySelectorAll('img.slide').forEach(scaled => {
      parent = scaled.parentNode,
      ratio = (parent.offsetWidth / scaled.offsetWidth),
      padding = scaled.offsetHeight * ratio;

    scaled.style.transform = 'scale(' + ratio + ')';
    scaled.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';

    parent.style.paddingTop = padding; // keeps the parent height in ratio to child resize
  })
}

scale();
window.onresize = scale();
```

Apparently none of this appears to have worked. Is there some easy solution to this problem? Maybe it can be solved with only a couple of CSS rules?

To recap, the problem is that the buttons for navigating the slide show are out of bounds for the smaller pictures and the slider buttons are not responsive when you make the viewport smaller/bigger or zoom in/out.

## StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-25inhy

## GitHub

https://github.com/munchkindev/js-25inhy/

Comment: Make your `.flex-container`  `inline-flex` instead of `flex` (so that it can shrink to the width the content requires), and add `position:relative`, so that it becomes the reference point for the absolute positioning of the buttons.

Comment: (That example is not a real use case, right? The images within _one_ slider instance will have the same width, yes? Because otherwise, I would really recommend that you rather center the smaller images in the available space - having the buttons jump around all the time, so that I would have to re-position my mouse cursor after every slide, that would be a massive p.i.t.a.)

Comment: @CBroe that solved 90% of the problems, now how do I make them properly wrap? It's not a real use case, the images are actually the same width, but I wanted to simulate viewport resizing :-) P.S. apparently in my real use case the buttons now appear out of bounds to the right :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "wrap". Are you talking about `wrap` in the flex sense? I don't see what sense that would make in combination with a _slider_ to begin with.

Comment: In case there's not enough space for two slider buttons in a row, but you're probably right. How do I properly make it scale now? Is my function any good for this use case?

Comment: You can't get that, as long as both buttons are positioned absolute on their own. You would have to put them put into a wrapper element, and then position that instead. If that element then gets to narrow, the buttons (now left in normal flow, instead of positioned), can wrap one below the other.

Comment: @CBroe maybe you could provide a short example? I failed to implement your suggestion. I think it would be good enough for an answer